# I get a blank screen

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, login, lubuntu

My laptop is displaying a blank screen today, instead of the normal login window.  I am using LUbuntu 14.04.

I can get into the terminal and login, but how do I start lxde after that and how do I get the normal graphical login screen back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you recently installed any GPU driver to your system? Try remove it and reboot first.

If there's not (many) things wrong in your system, `startx` command (after logging in) should bring the GUI back. If that doesn't help, try this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg
```

If `startx` succeeded, switch back to runlevel 5 by `sed s/^id:.*:initdefault:/id:5:initdefault:/`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you accidentally logged in the Openbox desktop environment? If you see the cursor, right-click, and exit. Then choose LXDE or Lubuntu before logging in.